# Installing rpy2 -2.1.5 on Mac OS X 10.5.8 fails

Tags: python, macos, r, rpy2

I've searched far and wide, read a previous question in stackoverflow but cant seem to solve the problem of installing rpy2 on my Mac with OS X 10.5.8.
I have Xcode 3.1.4 installed and R 2.1.11. 
when I run:

```
sudo python setup.py build install
```

I get this:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'rpy2.rinterface.rinterface' extension
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DR_INTERFACE_PTRS=1        -DHAVE_POSIX_SIGJMP=1 -DCSTACK_DEFNS=1 -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND=1 -Irpy/rinterface -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/i386 -c rpy/rinterface/rinterface.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/rpy/rinterface/rinterface.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/i386 -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/i386 -lRblas
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1: -lRlapack: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1: -lRblas: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1: -lRlapack: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1: -lRblas: linker input file unused because linking not done
powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1: -lRlapack: linker input file unused because linking not done
powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1: -lRblas: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc-4.0 -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -isysroot / -g -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/rpy/rinterface/rinterface.o -L-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -L-framework -LR -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules -L-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -L-framework -LR  L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules -lR -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-fat3-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/rinterface.so
ld: library not found for -lR
ld: library not found for -lR
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ldcollect2: : library ld returned 1 exit status
not found for -lR
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccFngK8H.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try a snapshot from the mercurial repository ?
(either branch version_2.1.x - future version 2.1.6 -,  or version_2.2.x - future version 2.2.0)

The build procedure has been streamlined and should accomodate better OS X.